# MPPT three-phase rectifier - BLDC generator project

Tags: arduino, boost, brushless-dc-motor, rectifier, mppt

I'm building a MCU controlled 3phase rectifier that allows voltage and current control.

The generator is a BLDC motor (Kv=100, Imax=30A, poles arrangement=36N42P.)

It will produce from 16V to 50V depending on RPM.

This unit will charge a 16s li-ion battery (67.2V) and/or feed another BLDC motor.

The whole setup is mounted inside an E-bike.  The generator replaces the pedal drive train.

In order to produce a decent voltage to feed the DC bus we need a DC-DC converter.

I've chosen to use a boost-converter circuit directly from the rectifier and motor inductance. This is often used in electric regenerative braking.

I built this schematic below and it worked as intended. I could get an adjustable voltage depending on the duty cycle and the motor RPM.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4unhK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current will be controlled through an N-MOSFET depending on the user demand. (User controlled torque or MPPT mode.)

Now I've designed a closed-loop circuit that allows me to regulate all this stuff.

A voltage that matches the DC bus and a current that matches the demand.

Because I'm a mechanical engineer and not an electrical engineer, I need help with MOSFET drivers and proper design of such a circuit.

[image: Prototype Schematic]

Do not pay much attention to the 12V supply and current sensor of my circuit. They are pre-assembled boards based on the chip drawn.

What are your impressions?
Are the MOSFET drivers correctly implemented?

Comment: If you're making a pedal generator to drive the bike or charge the batteries I suspect that with the losses that you would be much better off just pedaling the bike. (I've been had two mains-charged e-bikes since 2008.)

Comment: I understand the non-negligible losses compared to a direct drive chain. I expect half of the energy lost.
My vehicle will be a velomobile, a sort of recumbent trike with a roof. I don't want to deal with long noisy chains and dozens of gears to match the speed. I would like to use the flexibility of electricity to drive the vehicle to any speed with any pedaling force. Even charge-pedaling when stopped or downhill.

Comment: You should ask a more specific question. I'm not sure it's a good idea to ask electrical engineers to critique the electrical designs of a mechanical engineer. There are a number of potential issues with the circuit and it's difficult to provide meaningful answers to your vague questions.

Comment: It is always a good idea to ask questions anyway. The main question, and probably the reason I posted this is, is about the Mosfet driving circuit.